# Different Definitions of Teichmuller Space

Tags: surfaces, hyperbolic-geometry, teichmueller-theory

Let $S$ be a compact smooth surface.

On pg 276 of Farb and Margalit's *A Primer on Mapping Class Groups*, the following definition of the Teichmuller space of $S$ is given.

A **hyperbolic sturcture** on $S$ is a diffeomorphism $\phi:S\to X$, where $X$ is a surface with a finite area hyperbolic metric. The pair $(X, \phi)$ is called a **marking**. Two markings $(X, \phi_1:S\to X_1)$ and $(S, \phi_2:S\to X_2)$ are said to be **homotopic** if there is an isometry $I:X_1\to X_2$ such that $I\circ \phi_1$ is homotopic to $\phi_2$.

> **Definition 1.** The ***Teichmuller space*** of $S$ is the set of homotopy classes of all the markings on $S$.

On pg. 277, the authors give an alternate definition, as follows.

Let $H(S)$ be the set of all the hyperbolic metrics on $S$, and let the diffeomorphism group $\text{Diff}_0(S)$ of $S$ act on $H(S)$ by pullback.

> **Definition 2.** The ***Teichmuller space*** of $S$ is defined as the orbit space of $H(S)$ under the action of $\text{Diff}_0(S)$.

I am unable to see how the two definitions are equivalent. A Natural thing to do is the following.

Let $M(S)$ denote the set of all the markings of $S$. Define a map $M(S)\to H(S)$ by sending $(S, \phi:S\to X)$ to $\phi^*(g_X)$, where $g_X$ denotes the metric on $X$. Then I need to show that if $(S, \phi_1)$ and $(S, \phi_2)$ represent the same element in $H(S)/\text{Diff}_0(S)$, then $(S, \phi_1)$ and $(S, \phi_2)$ are homotopic. But I am unable to see why this should be true.

Comment: One thing you are missing is that homotopy implies isotopy in dimension 2.

Comment: @MoisheCohen I still fail to see how $(S, \phi_1)$ and $(S, \phi_2)$ turn out to be homotopic (equivalently, isotopic, as you pointed out) (refering to the last paragraph of my post). If $\phi_1^*(g_1)$ and $\phi_2^*(g_2)$ denote the same element in $H(S)/\text{Diff}_0(S)$, then there is a diffeomorphism $\alpha:S\to S$ such that $\alpha^*(\phi_2^*(g_2))=\phi_1^*(g_1)$. I need to produce an isometry $I:X_1\to X_2$ to that $I\circ \phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ are homotopic. The only candidate for $I$ I can think of is $\phi_2\circ\alpha\circ \phi_1^{-1}$. But I am unable to find the required homotopy.

Comment: @MoisheCohen I think Lee Mosher resolved my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: What's missing in the logic is an important theorem of surface topology:

> Theorem: Two self-diffeomorphisms $h_1,h_2 : S \to S$ of a surface are homotopic if and only if there exists $k \in \text{Diff}_0(S)$ such that $h_1 \circ k = h_2$.

Sometimes the second conclusion is expressed by saying that $h_1,h_2$ are "diffeotopic", although that is a rare term. On the other hand, the topological version of this theorem is almost always stated using the analogous terminology "isotopic": two self homeomorphisms of a surface are homotopic if and only if they are isotopic.

Comment: I am a bit confused now. Assuming the theorem you have stated, does it not follow that any diffeomopshim $f:S\to S$ is homotopic to the identity map (because $\text{id}\circ f= f$)? And thus any two diffeomorphisms $S\to S$ are homotopic. But homotopic maps induce the same map on the fundamental groups. But one can find diffeomorphisms of the torus which behave differently on fundamental groups. Can you please point out the mistake? Thanks.

Comment: The theorem says that if $h_1,h_2$ are homotopic *to each other* then they are diffeotopic *to each other*, meaning $h_1 \circ k = h_2$ for some $k \in \text{Diff}_0(S)$. It does not make any conclusion regarding whether one of $h_1$ or $h_2$ is diffeotopic to the identity map, which would require that $h_1 \circ k = Id$ or $h_2 \circ k = Id$. However, it *does* let you conclude that if $h_1$ is homotopic to $Id$ then $h_1$ is diffeotopic to $Id$; you simply apply the theorem $h_2 = Id$.

Comment: My reasoning is the following: Let $h_1, h_2:S\to S$ be two diffeomorphims. I want to show that $h_1$ and $h_2$ are homotopic (by using the theorem you stated). Since we have $\text{id}\circ h_1 = h_1$, and since $\text{id}$ is a diffeomorphism, we have $h_1$ is homotopic to $\text{id}$ (by the theorem). Similarly $h_2$ is homotopic to $\text{id}$. Since 'being homotopic to' is an equivalence relation, we have $h_1$ is homotopic to $h_2$. I still don't see my mistake.

Comment: Are trying to match your equation $\text{id} \circ h_1=h_1$ with the equation $h_1 \circ k = h_2$? If so, then you are matching symbols up incorrectly.

Comment: Perhaps I should change notation. Let $f:S\to S$ be a diffeomorphism. We have $\text{id}\circ f=f$. Now in the equation $h_1\circ k=h_2$, we put $h_1=\text{id}$, $k=f$, and $h_2=f$. Thus $h_1$ and $h_2$ are homotopic, which translates to $\text{id}$ is homotopic to $f$. So an arbitrary diffeomorphism $S\to S$ is homotopic to the identity map, and hence all diffeomorphisms are in the same homotopy class. Now do you see what I am trying to do? Or there is some error?

Comment: The hypothesis of the theorem requires that $k \in \text{Diff}_0(S)$, but $f$ is not assumed to be in $\text{Diff}_0(S)$. Are you perhaps overlooking the significance of the subscript $0$ in $\text{Diff}_0(S)$?

Comment: I am taking $\text{Diff}_0(S)$ to mean the set of all the diffeomorphisms of $S$. Is that wrong?

Comment: That is wrong. $\text{Diff}(S)$ is the group of all diffeomorphisms of $S$. $\text{Diff}_0(S)$ is the normal subgroup of those elements isotopic to the identity. You'll find those definitions on the first page of Farb-Maraglit.

Comment: Thank you. It's pretty embarrassing that I didn't read the first page of the book I cited. But reading linearly is a big waste of time.

Comment: Dunno, sometimes not reading linearly can waste time :-)